# ios app second screen

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am a beginner to the iOS app development and working on a sample app that consists of just two "screens" - the first screen authenticates the user against user id and password saved in a SQLite database table and the second screen displays list of users in the database if user authentication is successful. If authentication fails I would just like an alert displaying appropriate message to the user.

I somehow can not connect how to "go to the second screen" if user authentication is successful. How can I tell the application that now that the user is authenticated it is time to go to the second screen and display the list of users?

I apologize if the terminology I use is not standard iOS app development terminology but I am new and would like to fill the gaps in my understanding. Please feel free to direct me to any links/tutorials/documentation.

Thank you.

Comment: This is so very very vague... Code please?

Comment: I don't have the code yet and that's what I am trying to figure how to connect the first "screen" to the second.

Comment: Are you using StoryBoards or XIBs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigation is a fundamental and essential part of iOS programming and UX design.  Traditionally, views are managed by [ViewControllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), which in turn may be managed by [NavigationControllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) in stacks.  To naivgate between and away from controllers, we define two new verbs: Push and Pop.  To go to a new view, one *pushes* it onto the navigation stack.  To transition away from a view, one *pops* it off the stack.  And so, with these two paradigms, we can define simple transitions which are managed by the UINavigationController object.  Have a look at the navigation guide in the docs before you proceed any further.

Comment: Thank you, I think I have an idea of where to start from.

Answer (score 1):

You don't appear to have sufficient understanding of iOS basics for any of our answers to be helpful. A word of advice: don't waste your time wrestling with code before you have a bit more of a foundation; you will just become frustrated.

Take a few hours and review some of the videos in [Paul Haggarty's Standford iOS course](http://itunes.apple.com/us/itunes-u/ipad-iphone-application-development/id473757255).

Once you understand some of the building blocks and concepts of the API, things will move along much more quickly.

Comment: That's what I am aiming for. I know a lot of what I said was not too technical and I was looking for resources to fill gaps in my understanding before I wrote any code. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Are you developing against iOS with Storyboards?

If you start with the boilerplate "Master/Detail" template in Xcode for iOS 5 with Storyboards, you will get some sample code for a master view (uses a UITableView), detail view (uses a UIView with a label in it), and a segue between the two view controllers to go from master to detail, along with a "Back" navigation button that pops the detail view off and back to the master view.

The iPad boilerplate for that type of project is slightly different in the it uses a UISplitViewController to show both master and detail at the same time and doesn't use a segue between the two.

You could take a look at that boilerplate code, modify it, and go from there.

Comment: I have not looked into Storyboards yet as I don't think it's supported in iOS 4. Thanks for your suggestion.